# Finding probability of an absolute value function

Tags: probability, random-variables, absolute-value

$X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables, and $Y=|X|$

I want to find $P(Y \leq y) = P(|X| \leq y)$

So I attempted the following

$$\begin{align*}
P(|X| \leq y) & = P(|X|<y) && \text{ Since } X \text{ is a cont. r.v. } P(X=y)=0 \\
& = P(X<y)+P(X>-y)
\end{align*}$$

However, my in my textbook's solution,
$$P(|X| \leq y) = 1 - P(|X|>y) = 1 - (P(X>y)+P(X<-y))$$

I was wondering if these two equations are equal. If we rearrange my textbook's solution,
$$\begin{align*}
P(|X| \leq y) & = (1 - P(X>y)) - P(X<-y) \\
& = P(X<y)-P(X<-y)
\end{align*}$$

Therefore, we check if $$P(X>-y) = -P(X<-y)$$

$-P(X<-y) = -(1 -P(X>-y)) = -1 + P(X>-y)$

We can see that
$$-1+P(X>-y)\neq P(X>-y)$$

So I'm not sure if my calculations are wrong, but why does the book do $P(|X| \leq y) = 1 - P(|X|>y)$ instead of directly calculating $P(|X| \leq y) = P(X<y)+P(X>-y)$ and why are these approaches different?

Is it wrong that I assumed $P(|X| = y) = 0$?

Comment: The first line of your computation is wrong. $P(|x|<y)\neq P(x<y)+P(x>-y)$.

Comment: @lulu So how should I break down $P(|x|<y)$ ?

Comment: in the way they did. For $y>0$ you have $\mathbb P(|X| <y) = \mathbb P(X < y$ and $X >-y)$. As too decompose it, you rather need an union, not intersection, so they changed to complement, via : $ \mathbb P(|X| <y) = 1 - \mathbb P(|X| \ge y) = 1 - \mathbb P(X \ge y$ or $X \le -y)$, and now you indeed have an union of disjoint sets, so you can decompose

Comment: @DominikKutek Ohh that makes a lot of sense! Why is it when you decompose $P(|X| \geq y)$, you get union, but when you decompose $P(|X|<y)$ you get an intersection?

Comment: Because the condition $|X| < y$ means that you need BOTH $X <y$ and $X>-y$, whereas for the condition $|X| \ge y$ to hold, you need AT LEAST ONE of $X\ge y$ or $X \le -y$. It's the matter of condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy way to solve the problem

$$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[|X|\leq y]=\mathbb{P}[-y \leq X\leq y]=F_X(y)-F_X(-y)$$

---

Example:

Let $X\sim U[-1;1]$ . Find the distribution of $Y=|X|$

$$F_Y(y)=F_X(y)-F_X(-y)=\frac{y+1}{2}-\frac{1-y}{2}=y$$

Thus $Y\sim U[0;1]$

---

EDIT: answering to your comment,

$$\mathbb{P}[-y\leq X\leq y]=\underbrace{\mathbb{P}[-\infty\leq X\leq y]}_{=\mathbb{P}[X\leq y]=F_X(y)}-\underbrace{\mathbb{P}[-\infty\leq X\leq -y]}_{=\mathbb{P}[X\leq -y]=F_X(-y)}$$

Comment: Can you explain why $P[−y \leq X \leq y]=F_X(y) − F_X(−y)$

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose : , I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future

Comment: Sure! Actually I think I got why $P[−y \leq X \leq y]=F_X(y)−F_X(−y) $. The probability that $X$ is between $-y$ and $y$ is the probability that $X \leq y$ minus the probability that $X \leq -y$

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose :exactly. Anyway I edited my answer with details

Comment: Thanks! If you're not too busy, would you mind explaining what Dominik commented? i.e. Why is it when you decompose P(|X|≥y), you get union, but when you decompose P(|X|<y) you get an intersection?

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose : intersection is because $|X|<y$ is $X<y \cap X>-y$ but it can be solved as I showed, using $F_X$. I do not like the method your textbook used and that is the reason why I explained you a faster way to proceed